# How to run post build commands in meson?

Tags: meson-build

How can I do in meson to run a command after building a target?
Eg. I have an executable:

```
executable('target.elf', 'source1.c', 'source2.c')
```

And after `target.elf` built I want to execute a command (eg. `chmod -x target.elf`) on it.

I tried `custom_target()`, but that requires an output. I don't have new output, I just have `target.elf`. I tried `run_command()` but I didn't know how to execute it after the building.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should do.

```
project('tutorial', 'c')
exec = executable('target.elf', 'main.c', build_by_default : false)
custom_target('final binary',
          depends : exec,
          input : exec,
          output : 'fake',
          command : ['chmod', '+x', '@INPUT@'],
          build_by_default : true)
```

Note that because I want to always run the `fake` target, I'm using `custom_target()`.  However, the command `chmod + x demo` doesn't generate the file `fake` specified in `custom_target()`, successive `ninja` command will *always* run the target.

If you don't want this behaviour, there are two ways:

1. You can write a script which `chmod` the `target.elf` and then copies it to `target`, thus effectively creates the target file.  Make sure to change the `output` file in the `meson.build` if you do so.
2. If you don't mind typing `ninja chmod` instead of `ninja`, you can use [`run_target()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#run_target).

```
# optional
run_target('chmod',
       command : ['chmod', '+x', exec])
```

Another alternative is to use `install_mode` for [`executable()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#executable).

Also note that you should always use [`find_program()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#find_program) instead of plain `chmod`.  This example doesn't use it for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is I don't want fake files and I don't want to write all target names after `ninja`. I have more targets, and each of it will have a fake file. It's not elegant. And if someone forgot to write all targets nothing will warn him/her that something is missing. (A few scripts can solve this problem, but I don't think we should use scripts for it.)

Comment: Maybe I'm completely on a wrong way. I have a problem that nobody else complaining about and there isn't an elegant or simple solution. I think I'm using `meson` in a wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

[executable](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#executable) now has an argument `install_mode` (added 0.47.0) to specify the file mode in symbolic format and optionally the owner/uid and group/gid for the installed files.

I just noticed that [yasushi-shoji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640650/yasushi-shoji) has provided this answer already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have seen that answer. Sorry, but `install_mode` affects only the mode of installed files not the files in the build directory. I don't want to install that files, I use them in an image file (they are cross compiled binaries for another architecture). I have foreign binaries in the build directory with execute permission (of course they won't execute on the build machine).